# Reverse for 'detail' with arguments '('accounts/<int:pk>/',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['accounts/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$']

Tags: django

In my blog, i want when someone clicks on read more, it should direct the person to the log in page, which is working fine, then after inputting the log in credentials, it should take the person to the detail page and this where I'm getting the error above.

this is the code 
urls.py

```
from . import views
from django.urls import path
from.views import Home, Detail, CreatePost

urlpatterns = [
    path('', Home.as_view(), name='home'),
    path('register/', views.register, name='register'),
    path('login/', views.login, name='login'),
    path('logout/', views.logout, name='logout'),
    path('post/', CreatePost.as_view(success_url='/'), name='post'),
    path('accounts/<int:pk>/', Detail.as_view(), name='detail'),
]
```

The line below is from the entry_list.html
  `<a href="{% url 'login' %}" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Read More &rarr;</a>`

Then below is my login logic
    ```
    def login(request):

````
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']

        user = auth.authenticate(username=username, password=password)

        if user is not None:
            auth.login(request, user)
            return redirect('detail', 'accounts/<int:pk>/')
        else:
            return redirect('login')
    else:
        return render(request, 'login.html')
 ```
````

Answer (score 0):

```
path('accounts/<int:pk>/', Detail.as_view(), name='detail')
```

In that url definition, `<int:pk>` is a placeholder for the user id; it is not literally part of the url.

To redirect to the url, you must supply the user id:

```
return redirect('detail', pk=user.id)
```